# Determine a Kafka broker's ID from JMX

Tags: kafka

Given a broker host/ip is there a way to interrogate it to learn the broker ID other than by querying ZK? I'm trying to map the IP to the broker ID for monitoring. ZK is authenticated and I don't have access. I'm preferably looking for a value in JMX.

Answer (score 0):

The JMX values contains the kafka hostname: advertised.host.name or java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().

Have a look here http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#brokerconfigs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern `kafka.server:type=app-info,id=*` to obtain that broker's ID.

While sending to **broker 1**'s [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) endpoint, here is what it returns:

```
{
  "request": {
    "mbean": "kafka.server:id=*,type=app-info",
    "type": "read"
  },
  "value": {
    "kafka.server:id=1,type=app-info": {
      "StartTimeMs": 1575897801771,
      "Version": "2.3.1",
      "CommitId": "18a913733fb71c01"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": 1576320157,
  "status": 200
}
```